# Sql server clustered index on multiple column with different sort direction

Tags: sql, clustered-index

Can I have a clustered index created on multiple columns with different sort direction. For example
Create Clustered Index IX_Name on Table1(Empid asc,empname desc,sal asc)

If the answer is yes I am curious to know how, since clustered index store data in one particular order and in the above case we want index to created on three different sort direction.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you query your data by order "Empid asc,empname desc,sal asc", then you get your data in this order, yes? Clustered index (by this order) is ordered just in same way.

Comment: I don't understand the confusion. As a reduced example, consider an index on two columns `(a desc, b asc)` and four rows - `(1,a)`, `(2,a)`, `(1,b)` and `(2,b)`. Well, we sort them by that spec and index them in the order `(2,a)`, `(2,b)`, `(1,a)` and `(1,b)`. That's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can, and the values of the index are not even required to be Unique, if they are not, SQL Server will append a row identifier to each row to make it unique

Answer (score 0):

Cluster index based on single Unique/Primary key, on which base it make B-Tree ,if you want to use on multiple columns, we can't say it **cluster** indexing,it will **non-cluster** indexing because in non cluster indexing we use multiple column.